# Datasnap Getting 10054 - Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer. in TDBXCommand.Prepare

Tags: delphi, tcp, datasnap

I have a stable Delphi 10.2.3 TCP/IP Datasnap server and client that works 99.9% of the time perfectly well. Occasionally, the users receive a "10054 Connection reset by peer" error. I use Eurekalog and the callstack report shows me that the error occurs in the `DBXCommand.Prepare` statement in the generated `ClientClassesUnit`:

```
function TServerMethods3Client.UpdateTask(ID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if FUpdateTaskCommand = nil then
  begin
    FUpdateTaskCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FUpdateTaskCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
    FUpdateTaskCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods3.UpdateTask';
    FUpdateTaskCommand.Prepare; // --> exception is raised here
  end;
  FUpdateTaskCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32(ID);
```

Of course, the connection to the Datasnap server is achieved before the calll to the server method, using the usual:

```
SQLConnection1.Connected := True
Server := TServerMethods3Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
try
  Result := Server.UpdateTask(CDSTask.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger)
```

The problem isn't that the connecting to the Server failed, it's that the connection didn't "stay up", not even for a few milliseconds.

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Much as I didn't really want to, I ended up doing this:

```
function ClientModule1.UpdateTask: Boolean;
var
  i: integer
begin
  Result := False;
  i := 0;
  while (i < 3) and (not Result) do 
  begin
    if ServerConnect then
    begin
      Server := TServerMethods3Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
      try
        try
          Result := Server.UpdateTask(CDSTask.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
        except
        on e: exception do
        begin
          inc(i)
          if i = 3 then
            MessageDlg(e.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
          Sleep(1000);
        end
        end
      finally
        Server.Free;
        SQLConnection1.Connected := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function ClientModule1.ServerConnect: Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if SQLConnection1.Connected then
    SQLConnection1.Close;
  i := 0;
  while (not SQLConnection1.Connected) and (i < 3) do
  begin
    try
      SQLConnection1.Open;
    except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      inc(i)
      if i = 3 then
        MessageDlg(e.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      sleep(1000);
    end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```